Lebesgue measure of cartesian product of Gδ- sets
I cannot do this exercise so after a day of trying I'm asking for help. Suppose that $G\subseteq \mathbb{R^m}, H\subseteq \mathbb{R^n}$ are bounded $G_{\delta}$ sets. Show that $G\times H$ is a $G_{\delta}$ set and prove that $|G\times H|=|G||H|$.
Consider that I already demostrated that for boxes and open sets and also I shouldn't use the theorem that say that the measure of the cartesian product is the product of the measures of the sets(because this exercise is before the theorem).
I think I solved the first part:
If G and H are $G_{\delta}$ sets then there exist countable many open sets Uk and Vj such that $G=\bigcap_k U_k , H=\bigcap_j V_j$ so $G\times H= (\bigcap_k U_k)\times (\bigcap_j V_j)=\bigcap_k \bigcap_j(U_k \times V_j)$.Now $U_k \times V_j$ are open sets. Can this be considered a demostration for the first part?
For the second part I tried to use the lemma that says that we can arrenge a $G_{\delta}$ sets to have the form  $H=\bigcap V_j$ where $V1\supseteq V2 \supseteq ...$. So now the mesure $|H|=\lim_{j} |Vj|$ per continuity from above but still I'm not able to go on. Do you have any hints? thanks a lot
